# building a collection of excell sheets using wpf

Tags: c#

how do i get a list of the sheets in a particular workbook using wpf. i try running this code

```
    OleDbcon = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + openFileDialog.FileName + ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;");

    OleDbcon.Open();
    DataTable dt = OleDbcon.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);

    OleDbcon.Close();
    comboBox1.Items.Clear();
    for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++) 
    {
      comboBox1.Items.Add(sheetName);
    }
```

but it return one more that the number of sheets in the workbook

Comment: That one extra sheet returned, what is the name of it? Might be that one is the column name or hidden sheet?

Comment: one of the sheets is captured twice with slight difference, for examples; the sheet is STORE when I bind the list to combo box it appears as STORE, STORE$ I don't know where I got the STORE$. thanks @Dusan